# Receiving InvalidOperationException when a UserControl is created

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

My WPF application has a `UserControl` in it called `AlarmItem`.  Here's the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CarSystem.CustomControls.AlarmItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cs="clr-namespace:CarSystem.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100"
             DataContext="{Binding Path=Alarm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type cs:AlarmItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="FlashColor" Value="{DynamicResource NotPendingAlarmBorder}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExpired}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FlashColor" Value="{DynamicResource ExpiredAlarmBorder}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPending}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsFlashing" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsWhiteListAlarm}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FlashColor" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteListAlarmBorder}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="AlarmItemBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsExpired}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPending}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="5" 
            Height="100"
            Name="Border"
            Style="{StaticResource AlarmItemBorderStyle}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Width="100">
        <Border.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="FlashingStoryboard" AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Duration="00:00:01"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"   Value="Black" />
                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="{Binding Path=FlashColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:AlarmItem}}}" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Border.Resources>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlashStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FlashingOn"
                             Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FlashingStoryboard}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="FlashingOff" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" 
                   Name="AlarmImage" 
                   Source="{Binding Path=Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cs:AlarmItem}}}" 
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            <cs:ResponseTimer Expired="Timer_Expired"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              HideIfExpired="True"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              MinHeight="10"
                              x:Name="TheTimer"
                              TimeoutPeriod="00:02:30"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind for this control has the following code in it that runs when the `IsFlashing` property changes:

```
private void OnIsFlashingChanged( object sender, bool flashNow ) {
    if ( flashNow ) {
        if ( !VisualStateManager.GoToElementState( Border, "FlashingOn", true ) ) {
            Log.Debug( "AlarmItem.xaml.cs:  Visual State Manager transition failed." );
        }
    } else {
        if ( !VisualStateManager.GoToElementState( Border, "FlashingOff", true ) ) {
            Log.Debug( "AlarmItem.xaml.cs:  Visual State Manager transition failed." );
        }
    }
}

private static void OnIsFlashingInvalidated( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
    AlarmItem alarmItem = (AlarmItem) d;

    alarmItem.OnIsFlashingChanged( d, (bool) e.NewValue );
}
```

The line that sets the visual state for the Border to `FlashingOn` throws the following `InvalidOperationException` when it executes:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'BorderBrush' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.

What have I done wrong?  I recently added the `Style` and the triggers that set the `IsFlashing` property; in the past, I did it in the code-behind and this error did not occur then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, trial & error, and heartache, the reason I'm getting the error is because the `Border` class's `BorderBrush` property is a `Brush`, not a `SolidColorBrush`.  `Brush` is an abstract type that `SolidColorBrush` and all the various gradient brush classes descend from.